# How Movie Py write_videofile can use whole CPU while render

Tags: python, moviepy

I've got a macbook with M1 processor (arm64)

While MoviePy renders video file CPU Usage doesn't grows more than one core and the same for ffmpeg. But i've got 8 core and wanna to use all of them to that.

How it can be solved?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to utilize multiprocessing and multithreading efficiently to convert 1000s of video files to audio using python in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100395/how-to-utilize-multiprocessing-and-multithreading-efficiently-to-convert-1000s-o)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100395/how-to-utilize-multiprocessing-and-multithreading-efficiently-to-convert-1000s-o) out. The problem you have is that python is by deffinition monothread so unless you use multithreading (that isn't actually real multithreading but multi instancing) you will only ever use one thread of your processor. You can try to multithread but as said in the post I linked, it won't be easy to do considering the nature of the task.

Comment: Yes, i can split my movie to some parts and make several video files but there must be final step - to combine them together with one audio file.

I can't find a relevant example for me